# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass when using maps and twitter search (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, maps

Im having an error when tryin to display the result of a twitter search in a maps.

The error is:

> NoMethodError in MapController#index undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass Extracted source (around line #27):

```
      @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(body["statuses"]) do |status, marker|
      marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "/map/info", :locals => { 26 :object => status})
27        marker.lat status["geo"]["coordinates"][0]
28        marker.lng status["geo"]["coordinates"][1]
    end 
      end
```

Here is my controller:

```
  def index
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    user_access = prepare_access_token_user(@user.access_token, @user.access_secret, @user.consumer_token, @user.consumer_secret)
    #that gps point is Paris
    #&geocode=48.8567,2.3508,1000mi (within 1000 miles)
    #q=%23cats&result_type=recent&count=100&geocode=48.8567,2.3508,1000mi
    @response = user_access.request(:get, "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23cats&result_type=recent&count=100&geocode=48.8567,2.3508,1000mi")
    body = JSON.parse(@response.body)

  @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(body["statuses"]) do |status, marker|
  marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "/map/info", :locals => { :object => status})
    marker.lat status["geo"]["coordinates"][0]
    marker.lng status["geo"]["coordinates"][1]
end 
  end
```

Does anybody idea about why is the error??

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like some of element references in `marker.lat status["geo"]["coordinates"]` returns `nil` (ie. key not found) you try further reference. I'd bet `status` is set to `nil` the way you are passing a block to `Gmaps4rails.build_markers(body["statuses"])`. Replace `do…end` with braces `{…}` or use parens around do…end. Be aware due to lower precedence of do…end `@hash` is assigned first, *then* the adjacent block is passed.

Comment: Did you check that `body` actually contains what you expect? You need to debug your `body` contents. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html

Comment: Actually I have checked the returning information from twitter and there are a few twitter which coordinates are nil. How could I fix that?. Im not understanding your answer, I didn´t write thta code, it is from a college tutorial.
I think that is the problem, because with another search which I have store in a url is working.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like either `status`, `status["geo"]`, or `status["geo"]["coordinates"]` is `nil`, and ruby is trying to call the `[]` method on an instance on the `nil` class, which obviously doesn't respond to array indexing using the `[]` method.

I agree with David's comment, it's most likely `status` is `nil`. Depending on what you're trying to do, you might add something like `continue unless status` to the first line of your block.

Comment: I think that you both are right, that is the problem. Look at a part of the entry:: , "geo"=>nil, "coordinates"=>nil, "place"=>nil, "contributors"=>nil, 
The problem is that I have no idea of how to fix that, Im new with this.
I have tried what you told me:
  @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(body["statuses"]) do |status, marker|
    continue unless status

But still fail

Comment: you could set a default value: begin; nil[1][2][3]; rescue; 0.0 end # => 0.0

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand your solution. What i need to add?